# Show the inequality $\lvert \sin(z)\rvert > \frac{2}{\pi}$ for $z$ on the circle of radius $(n+1/2) \pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

I want to show the inequality $\lvert\sin(z)\rvert > \frac{2}{\pi}$ for $z$ on the circle of radius $(n+1/2) \pi$.
What I have gotten so far is using the fact that

$\lvert\sin(x+iy)\rvert^2 = \sin^2(x)+ \sinh^2(y)$

to get

$\sin^2((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi \cos(\theta)) + \sinh^2((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi \sin(\theta)) > \frac{4}{\pi^2}$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$

I verified on a graphing calculator that such statement is true, but have not been able to present any proper argument.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WLOG we can consider only $x, y \ge 0$, so $y = \sqrt{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2 - x^2}$

Observe (by staring at the graph) that
$f(x) := \sin^2{x} + \sinh^2{y} = \sin^2{x} + \sinh^2{\sqrt{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2 - x^2}}$ is decreasing from $x = 0$ to $x = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi $. To prove it, I will use the following two inequalities (you can come up with a proof):

(1) $\sin{x} \le x$

(2) $\sinh{x} \ge x$

Now for $x \ge 0$, we have

$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 2\sin{x}\cos{x} + 2\sinh{y}\cosh{y} \cdot \frac{-x}{y} \\
&= \sin{2x} - 2x \cdot \frac{\sinh{2y}}{2y} \\
&\le 2x\left(1 - \frac{\sinh{2y}}{2y}\right) \text{  ...... by (1)} \\
&\le 2x\left(1 - 1\right) \text{  ...... by (2)} \\
&\le 0.
\end{align}$

Therefore $f(x)$ must attain minimum at $x = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$, and we actually proved a stronger bound:

$|\sin{z}| \ge \sqrt{f\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)} = 1$

Comment: Derivative of y w.r.t x is =x/y. So $f’(x) = \sin(2x) - 2x* \sinh(2y)/2y \leq 2x(1-1) = 0$

Comment: oops edited thanks a lot