# Completeness of Exponentials Using Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

In order to show completness of $\{ e^{inx} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ for $L^2[0,2\pi]$, it is enough to show that, if $f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$ is orthogonal to all exponentials, then $f=0$. I believe that Complex Analysis can be used to accomplish this by considering the function
$$
             F(\lambda)=\frac{1}{e^{-2\pi i\lambda}-1}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\lambda t}f(t)dt.
$$
**Outline:** To do this, suppose $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\lambda t}f(t)dt=0$ for $\lambda=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\cdots$. Then $F$ has only removable singularities, and it extends to an entire function of $\lambda$. If $F$ can be shown to be uniformly bounded on a nested sequence of contours (squares or circles, for example,) then that should be enough to show that $F$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ and, hence, a constant function. So there would be a constant $C$ such that
$$
              \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\lambda t}f(t)dt = C(e^{-2\pi i\lambda}-1)
$$
And that constant would have to be $0$. Then it would follow that all derivatives at $\lambda=0$ would be $0$, leading to the conclusion that $\int_0^{2\pi}t^n f(t)dt=0$. Now, by Weierstrass approximation, it would follow that $f\equiv 0$.

**Can all of this be made rigorous?**

Comment: The main difficulty seems to be the proof that $F$ is uniformly bounded, of course. (If this is true). However, I also do not see why $C$ should be $0$. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : Take a limit in $\lambda$ toward $\infty$ that forces $e^{-i\lambda t}$ to vanish and $e^{-2\pi i\lambda}$ to vanish. For the other part of your question: If you have a holomorphic function uniformly bounded on a sequence  of expanding squares or circles, I was thinking that Cauchy's theorem could then be used to bound things. Maybe that doesn't work out, but it seems like it should because of the Cauchy representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use $z=x+iy$ instead of $\lambda$. One can show that

1. $|F(z)|$ is uniformly bounded on circles of radius $n + 1/2$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, and
2. $\lim_{n \to \infty } F((n+\frac 12)y) = 0$.

(1) implies that $F$ is constant (using the maximum modulus principle and Liouville's theorem). (2) then implies that $F$ is identically zero.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $\Vert f \Vert_2 \le 1$. Then
$$
 \left| \int_0^{2 \pi}  e^{-izt} f(t)\, dt \right|^2 \le \int_0^{2 \pi} | e^{-izt}|^2 \, dt =  \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{2yt} \, dt = \frac{e^{4\pi y}-1}{2y}
$$
and
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{e^{-2 \pi i z}-1} \right|^2 
 = \left| \frac{e^{i \pi z}}{e^{- \pi i z}-e^{i \pi z}} \right|^2
 = \frac{4 e^{-2\pi y}}{|\sin(\pi z)|^2}
$$
so that
$$
 |F(z)|^2 \le \frac{ 4\sinh(2 \pi y)}{y |\sin(\pi z)|^2} \quad \text{for } z = x+iy , y \ne 0\, .
$$

From now on we assume that $|z|= n + 1/2$ with a positive integer $n$.

*Case 1:* $|y| \le 1$. Without loss of generality, $0 < y < 1$. The slope $\frac{\sinh(2 \pi y)}{y}$ is maximal for $y=1$ because of the convexity of the hyperbolic sine. And $|\sin(\pi z)| \ge 1$ for $|\pi z| = (n+1/2) \pi$ is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3169870/42969). It follows that
$$
 |F(z)|^2 \le 4 \sinh(2 \pi) \, .
$$
For continuity reasons this holds in the case $y=0$ as well.

*Case 2:* $|y| > 1$. Then $|\sin(\pi z)|^2 = \sin^2(\pi  x) + \sinh^2 (\pi y) \ge \sinh^2 (\pi y)$, so that
$$
|F(z)|^2 \le \frac{4 \sinh(2 \pi y)}{y \sinh^2 (\pi y)} = \frac{4}{y \tanh(\pi y)}
\le \frac{4}{y \tanh(\pi)} \, .
$$

These estimates together show that (1) and (2) are true.

Comment: Thanks for asking me to put that back! I saw no interest in the question before, and began to wonder if the ideas were correct or not. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be exactly what Jeff Rauch does in his notes “Fourier Analysis from Complex Analysis”, pag.7:

[http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rauch/555/fouriercomplex.pdf](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Erauch/555/fouriercomplex.pdf)

The only difference is that Rauch uses $\sin \pi \lambda$ in place of your $e^{-i2\pi \lambda}-1$. To obtain the key uniform boundedness, he uses the “Cauchy inequalities”, but to be honest I don’t understand this fully.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. That is very helpful.